# Программа работает неверно , помогите найти баг

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Вот задача,

Вам дана нижнетреугольная матрица из `n` строк (`i`-й ряд состоит ровно из `i` элементов, расположенных в столбцах с номерами от 1 до `i`). В каждой ячейке матрицы записана маленькая латинская буква. Также у вас есть пустая строка `s`.

Вы стоите в ячейке с координатами `(1, 1)` (первая строка, первый столбец). На каждом ходу можно делать переход на одну ячейку ниже или на одну ячейку по диагонали вправо-вниз. То есть из ячейки с координатами `(i, j)` можно попасть в ячейки `(i+1, j)` или `(i+1, j+1)`.

Каждый раз, когда вы попадаете в новую ячейку, к строке `s` в конец приписывается буква, стоящая в этой ячейке. Найдите лексикографически минимальную строку, которую можно получить при переходе из первой строки матрицы в последнюю (`n`-ю).

#### Формат входных данных:

В первой строке задано число `n` (1 ≤ n ≤ 5⋅10<sup>3</sup>).
Затем идёт `n` строк, в `i`-й находится строка из `i` символов, отвечающая первым `i` столбцам `i`-й строки матрицы.

#### Формат результата:

Выведите искомую строку.

#### Примеры

Входные данные

```
3
o
nu
mwb
```

Результат работы

```
onm
```

Входные данные

```
4
a
bb
czc
defr
```

---

Слышал , что как-то решается через дп, но не знаю как.

Ещё не проходит тест

```
4
a
bb
ccc
zzzza
```

Код

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

vector<vector<char>> a (10000 , vector<char> (10000));
vector<string> nums;

void right(int n) {
    string res;
    res+=a[1][1];
    int idxI = 1;
    int idxJ = 1;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < n;i++) {
        if ((a[idxI + 1][idxJ] < a[idxI + 1][idxJ + 1])) {
            res+= a[idxI + 1][idxJ];
            idxI++;
        }
        else {
            res+=a[idxI + 1][idxJ + 1];
            idxI++;
            idxJ++;
        }
    }
    nums.push_back(res);
}
void left(int n) {
    string res;
    res+=a[1][1];
    int idxI = 1;
    int idxJ = 1;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < n;i++) {
            if ((a[idxI + 1][idxJ] < a[idxI + 1][idxJ + 1])) {
                res+= a[idxI + 1][idxJ];
                idxI++;
            }  else if(a[idxI + 1][idxJ] == a[idxI + 1][idxJ + 1]){
                res+= a[idxI + 1][idxJ];
                idxI++;
                right(n);
                }
            else {
                res+=a[idxI + 1][idxJ + 1];
                idxI++;
                idxJ++;
            }
    }
    nums.push_back(res);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= n;i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i ;j++) {
        scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    left(n);
    string res = nums[0];
    for(auto x : nums) {
        res = min(res , x);
    }
    cout << res << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не проходит тест из-за ошибки? Или не проходит по времени?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавим к каждой строке заведомо бОльший символ (например, "z"+1= "{") (это не обязательно, если усложнить проверки для `prev` ниже)

Создадим вектор `best[]` длиной n для лучших символов каждой строки (не обязательно меньших, а тех, путь к которым составляет лексикографически наим. строку), в нулевой элемент запишем символ из верхушки `a[0][0]`, остальные заполним всё той же скобкой.

Для каждого элемента остальных строк - смотрим, стоит ли вверху или вверху-слева тот же символ, что записан в предыдущий `best` (от проверок для последнего и первого символа избавляемся благодаря скобке в конце)

```
prev = min(a[i-1][(k + i - 1) % i], a[i-1][k]);
```

Если да, то обновляем `best` для текущей строки

```
if (prev == best[i-1])
    best[i] = min(best[i], a[i][k]);
```

Если нет, то текущий символ никак не войдёт в результат, и мы его меняем на скобку, чтобы он не мешал дальше - хотя он и может совпасть с с лучшим по строке, но недостижим по оптимальному пути.

В результате `best[]` содержит лексикографически минимальную строку.

Код на Python (там `s[-1]` указывает на последний элемент списка, поэтому `(k + i - 1) % i` не требуется)

```
import random

def bestpath(l):
    n = len(l)
    best = ['{']*n
    best[0] = l[0][0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        for k in range(i+1):
            prev = min(l[i-1][k-1], l[i-1][k])
            if prev == best[i-1]:
                best[i] = min(best[i], l[i][k])
            else:
                l[i][k] = '{'
    return best
    
l = []
n = 5
for i in range(1,n+1):
    l.append([chr(97  + random.randint(0,6)) for _ in range(i)])
    l[-1].append('{')
    print(''.join(l[-1][:-1]))

print('--------')
print(''.join(bestpath(l)))
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/Y4L2sc)

Comment: При `a` `ab` `aaa` `bbba`, результат должен быть `aaab`. Для каждого ряда оптимальным может быть только один уникальный символ, но если в ряду такой символ повторяется, не каждая копия будет частью оптимального маршрута

Comment: @extrn Про повторные символы именно такие мысли у меня и были, видимо, условие достижимости упустил. Подумаю ещё попозже.

Comment: Если точнее, я выкинул дополнительную таблицу, когда показалось, что и без неё получается :(

Comment: Я обычно начинаю с наивного очевидного решения, которое очень сложно запороть, и сравниваю его результаты на рандомных тестах с оптимизированным решением. https://ideone.com/JCSqUG

Comment: @extrn Дык часто кажется, что хороший тест написать дольше, чем решение, которое уже вроде на ладони...  Без таблицы удалось обойтись